# Gridview Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I GridView data Update in other forms then data update but when close this form then gridview data refresh not response automatically in C# win-forms application
Here my Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aCatagory=new tbl_Catagory();
    aContext = new RM_Inventory_DataContext();

    var product = (from p in aContext.tbl_Catagories
                   where p.CatagoriesID == Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text) 
                   select p).Single();

    product.CatagoriesName = textBox2.Text;

    aContext.SubmitChanges();
    this.Close();
    AddCatagories addCatagories=new AddCatagories();
    addCatagories.GridView();
}


public void GridView()
{
    gridControl1.DataSource = new RM_PM_Inverntory_Management_System.RM_Inventory_DataContext().tbl_Catagories;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding gridview after assigning the datasource.

```
public void GridView()
{
gridControl1.DataSource = What ever Data Source You have
gridControl1.DataBind();
}
```